# Confirming file content against hash

Tags: java, file, hash, checksum

I have a requirement to 'check the integrity' of the *content* of files. The files will be written to CD/DVD, which might be copied many times.  The idea is to identify copies (after they are removed from Nero etc.) which copied correctly.

Am rather new to this, but a quick search suggests that [`Arrays.hashCode(byte[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28byte%5B%5D%29) will fit the need.  We can include a file on the disk that contains the result of that call for each resource of interest, then compare it to the `byte[]` of the `File` as read from disk when checked.

Do I understand the method correctly, is this a valid way to go about checking file content?

If not, suggestions as to search keywords or strategies/methods/classes would be appreciated.

---

Working code based on the answer of Brendan.  It takes care of the problem identified by VoidStar (needing to hold the entire `byte[]` in memory for getting the hash).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

class TestHash {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("TestHash.java");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        CRC32 crcMaker = new CRC32();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            crcMaker.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        long crc = crcMaker.getValue(); // This is your error checking code
        System.out.println("CRC code is " + crc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Arrays.hashCode()` is designed to be very fast (used in hash tables). I highly recommend not using it for this purpose.

What you want is some sort of error-checking code like a [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Java happens to have a class for calculating these: [CRC32](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html):

```
InputStream in = ...;
CRC32 crcMaker = new CRC32();
byte[] buffer = new byte[someSize];
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    crcMaker.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
long crc = crcMaker.getValue(); // This is your error checking code
```

Comment: Thanks much.  I now have working code (edited into question) that I am happy with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

You need to create a checksum file
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=216274

```
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    CheckedInputStream check = 
      new CheckedInputStream(file, new CRC32());
    BufferedInputStream in = 
      new BufferedInputStream(check);
    while (in.read() != -1) {
        // Read file in completely
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Checksum is " + 
      check.getChecksum().getValue());
```

Comment: `checksum`!  I knew there was a relevant term I was forgetting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you load the entire file and pass it in, it will perform as expected. *However* it will consume as much RAM as the file is big, which is not necessary for this task. If you instead hash the file in smaller blocks as you stream it from storage, then you can avoid wasting memory. You could, for example, xor together the hashes of each block to create a final hash, or find a hash implementation that expects data to be streamed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I had not thought about the difficulties of loading the entire file into memory.  That can be solved by using the CRC32 as suggested by Brendan.